# Migrating from Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDb to Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos for data access. Not all options available

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am in the process of migrating our codebase which accesses CosmosDB via Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB v2.7.0 into an approach using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos v3.2.0. During this process the NuGet package "Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB v2.7.0" has been replaced with "Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos v3.2.0".

Almost all the code has been migrated to use the components provided in the new NuGet as below.

- SqlQuerySpec             : QueryDefinition
- DocumentClient           : CosmosClient
- DocumentClientException      : CosmosException
- query.ExecuteNextAsync()      : query.ReadNextAsync()

The issue comes when we try to configure connection properties which we used to do with the old NuGet package's `ConnectionPolicy` class like below.

```
var policy = new ConnectionPolicy()
{
EnableEndpointDiscovery = true,
EnableReadRequestsFallback = true,
ConnectionMode = connectionMode,
ConnectionProtocol = Protocol.Http,
UseMultipleWriteLocations = useMultipleWriteLocations
};
```

Could anyone help me find how to set similar properties like `EnableEndpointDiscovery`, `EnableReadRequestsFallback`, `ConnectionProtocol` in `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos` namespace? I was only able to set the region with the `CosmosClientOptions.ApplicationRegion` property. Is the package `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos` not offering all customizations which the `Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDb` used to provide? Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ConnectionMode, please see ConnectionMode in CosmosClientOptions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.cosmosclientoptions.connectionmode?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Cosmos_CosmosClientOptions_ConnectionMode

ConnectionProtocol will be automatically set accordingly.

UseMultipleWriteLocations is not needed anymore, as the SDK will automatically detect the capabilities on the account.

EnableEndpointDiscovery was true by default, setting it to true makes no difference, were you setting it for some particular reason? The same with EnableReadRequestsFallback.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that the properties you mentioned were deprecated and replaced with their `true` defaults. I'm not sure there's a use-case where you wouldn't want `EnableEndpointDiscovery` or `EnableReadRequestsFallback` to be set to true.
There are some new options in the pipeline for the next release that might be relevant thouhg. [Notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sdk-dotnet-standard#unreleased) see #814

As for the connection mode, I think that when using `ConnectionMode.Direct` you are using TCP and when using `ConnectionMode.Gateway` you are going to use Http(s) based on the provided account endpoint.